# Compute an arc length with start/end/center points and an axis

Tags: math

I need to compute an arc length with some datas:

- `Start` point with coords (Xs, Ys, Zs)
- `End` point with coords (Xe, Ye, Ze)
- `Center` point with coords (Xc, Yc, Zc)
- `Axis` vector with components (Xa, Ya, Za)

The `Arc` starts on `Start` point, finishes on `End` point, has a radius equals to `DistanceBetween(Center, Start)` and `DistanceBetween(Center, End)` and his direction is defined by the `Axis` vector.

**Example :**

```
Arc {
  Start   { -18.123, -11.805, 0 },
  End     { -17.167,  -0.553, 0 },
  Center  {  -9.421,  -6,877, 0 },
  Axis    { 0, 0, -1 }
}
```

Note: in this example, the arc has a clockwise direction

**My problem is:** I can compute the large or the small length but I am unable to determine the good value depending on the direction of the axis.

Some help will be welcome.

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't it possible that you get input data that can't be made into an arc? Given a `Start` and `End` point, the center can only be an arbitrary point in the plane which has equal distance to both points. Wouldn't a `Radius` parameter be better instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your data is all self-consistent (center has to be equidistant from the start and end, and the axis should be perpendicular to the plane containing start, end, and center), the arc length is the measure in radians of the angle Start -> Center -> End multiplied by the radius (distance from Center to Start, or equivalently, distance from Center to End). The measure of the angle can be found by the cosine law: `C^2 = A^2 + B^2 - 2AB cos theta` where `C` is the distance from Start to End, `A` is the distance from Center to Start, `B` is the distance from Center to End. In this case the formula can be simplified to `C^2 = 2R^2 - 2R^2 cos theta` which can be solved for `cos theta` and then inverse cosine taken to obtain `theta`.

If I understand correctly, you have gotten that far, but the problem is that there are generally two values for the inverse of `cos`, corresponding to the short and long arc between start and end, and you don't know which to pick.

The principal branch of inverse cosine, which is what you get if you use the library function `arccos`, will always give the short angle. You will need another way to figure out whether the correct angle is short or long.

The way I recommend is to use the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Definition). The formula of interest is

```
a x b = |a| |b| sin(\theta) n
```

where `a` is the vector Start - Center, `b` is the vector `End - Center`, `|a|=|b|=R`, and `n` is the unit vector determined by your axis. You already have the angle theta, more or less, from the cosine law, so you don't need to calculate `arcsin`; all you are really interested in at this point is the sign of `sin(theta)`. If `a x b` and `n` are in the same direction, `sin(theta)>0` and you take the short arc determined by the cosine law. If `a x b` and `n` are in opposite directions, `sin(theta)<0`, and you take the long arc determined by the cosine law.

You can tell whether `a x b` and `n` are in the same or opposite directions by taking their dot product. If the dot product is positive, they are in the same direction. If the dot product is negative, they are in opposite directions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help